# Are two fans on one molex safe?

Tags: cooling

Are two fans on one molex safe? One fan is 12v 0.15amp and the other is 12v 0.7amp. Is this set up safe? Can power unit handle a 0.7amp fan which makes an electric drill like noise?

Nothing else except these two is attached to the molex. Two SATA hard disks are run by the mobo.

Comment: You would need to look at the specs of your PSU. Likely yes.

Comment: Agreeing with Seth, best to double check your PSU first, but I actually ran 3 fans from a single Molex for a prolonged period of tome before purchasing a fan controller. The fans ran a little slower than they normally would, but nothing ever went wrong!